# Could a virus extend life-span?

Tags: biology, technology, science-fiction, diseases, bio-mechanics

Would it be possible for a virus to extend the average human life-span (but only by about 50-70 years max) if the infected people kept it controlled enough where it wouldn't (alternatively) kill them (for example- with minimal necessary treatment and technological re-enforcement of the body's systems)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, as AndreiROM mentioned, the reason we age is because our cells lose a little information each time they replicate. We have evolved to handle this by capping our chromosomes with telomeres, sequences of repeating nonsense DNA, so that we don't lose anything important for the first many replications. It has been proposed that extending the telomeres could extend life. In theory, it would be possible to create a virus that inserted additional telomere sequences into the cell, allowing the cell a longer reproductive life and the person a longer life in general. This would have the added bonuses of flexible time-lengths (if you want a person's life extended by a longer span, give him one virus, if you want it extended by a shorter amount, give him a different virus) as well as retaining youth/middle-age. We get wrinkles and such because our cells are no longer all replicating like they used to, but with added telomere, we would still look and act like our younger selves.

Note that this sort of virus will only work to slow aging from the point of infection on. It will not reverse ageing. It could be re-applied on a regular basis to grant immortality, and the virus need not be kept alive in the host. Once it deposits it's genes, it can be killed, however it is necessary for all the body's cells to be affected, so to make this actually work, the virus would probably cause either a near-death experiance (when the virus replicates within the body- it cannot be treated until the procedure is complete, and replication is what causes the symptoms of disease) or a prolonged period of mild effects.

The easiest way for a virus like this to come about would be through engineering, but if you want it to be natural, explain it lightly. Really, all a telomere is is a string of DNA that the cell can afford to lose, so any viral DNA that could be attached properly to the ends of the chromosomes could function as a telomere. Presumably this virus comes from another planet, or some long-lost cave or some such, so it could be explained as the human cell's response to this particular viral code. The host cell just sticks the sequence at the end of the chromosome, the sequence does not code for any human proteins, so it functions like a telomere. This could be tied in to religion if you like. Maybe the reason the Mayans were so concerned with the future was because they knew that some of them would be living in it. The sacred caves of South America could contain the source of the virus, and the priests/priestesses went to talk to the gods, got infected, and lived for centuries. This could also be tied in to human sacrifice. Maybe the virus lives in some kind of cave creature that must be fed. Like a subterranean virus factory.

Sorry, I went off on a tangent, but the point is, yes, it is totally possible for such a virus to exist, either man-made or natural, and you can tie it into all kinds of stuff if you want to give an extensive background.

Answer (score 2):

Our body is constantly regenerating and replacing damaged cells. We grow old because as those cells are replaced, the quality of the copy's genetic material is slowly damaged.

If we could figure out how to tweak our bodies and replicate those cells *perfectly*, then we would be immortal.

Viruses, by their very nature, target a cell, and inject their own genetic material into it, thus converting it for their purposes. I suppose it is *conceivable* (although insanely improbable) that a virus might inadvertently cause that aging mechanism to "malfunction".

This would, for all intents and purposes, however, be pseudo-science, aka fiction.

Comment: Alternative (borrowing from a work of fiction), if the virus actually repaired the imperfections; same end result, just a slightly different path to get there.

Comment: Wouldn't the untamed reproduction of undying cells be the same as cancer? Still +1 for the idea, seems that it would work otherwise

Comment: Note that all improbability of the virus evolving this ability is thrown out the door if the virus has been engineered by humans